# How to iterate on map while removing items?

Tags: haxe

I am new to haxe and I need to remove items while iterating on a dictionary of elements. Is this possible in Haxe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

```
    var map:Map<Int, String> = [100 => 'a', 101 => 'b', 102 => 'c'];

    trace(map); // {100 => a, 101 => b, 102 => c}

    for (v in map.keys()){
         if (v == 101) map.remove(v);
    }

    trace(map); // {100 => a, 102 => c}
```

You can play with the example at https://try.haxe.org/#AE894

Comment: There's no guarantee that the `keys()` iterator will cope with insertion/removal (as it is with `iterator()`).  Most targets do create a List or Array for `keys()`, so they are safe, but not all do that (i.e. [Java comes to mind](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/blob/5979a08/std/java/_std/haxe/ds/StringMap.hx#L386)).

Comment: Seems like this is only a problem for insertion. Since the OP only asked about removing items, this answer is safe even in Java and C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove while looping over the keys of the map.

```
trace("Remove every 2nd key");
for(k in myMap.keys())
{
  if(k % 2 == 0)
     myMap.remove(k);
}
```

See my example here: https://try.haxe.org/#d3525